# Locking only on a single entry point

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

I am utilizing an `ExcutorService` to submit tasks to run in parallel. The order of the tasks does not matter. However, the service may change, specifically when the requested size of the pool needs to change.

```
public class Service {

    private volatile ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

    private final ReentrantLock serviceLock = new ReentrantLock();

    public Future<Object> postRequest(final Callable<Object> request) {
        try {
            serviceLock.lock(); // ?
            return service.submit(request);
        } finally {
            serviceLock.unlock(); // ?
        }
    }

    public void setSize(final int size) {
        try {
            if (size <= 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("service pool size must positive");
            }
            serviceLock.lock();

            service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(size);
        } finally {
            serviceLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, I don't think I need the locking and unlocking in the `postRequest` method when it is the only method being called.

I only need to lock on `postRequest` during access to `setSize`. Otherwise, the extra time required to lock and unlock is just pointless. I believe this is necessary, seeing as the size will rarely change (maybe once or twice) compared to hundreds of requests being submitted.

**Is there a way to avoid the locking on `postRequest` when it is not needed (when `setSize` is not being accessed)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Executor is in fact a ThreadPoolExecutor you can apply a cast and use its setMaximumPoolSize method.

You may add a type check in the setSize method in case of a future update of the JVM spec.

```
    if (e instanceof ThreadPoolExecutor) {
        ((ThreadPoolExecutor) e).setMaximumPoolSize(size);
    }
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setMaximumPoolSize(int)

Comment: If the OP wants the features of a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, then the OP should create a variable of that type, and explicitly create an object of that type.  Using type casting or other means to subvert the intent of library functions is a code smell.  It's an even stronger smell when there's other, simpler ways to solve the problem.

Comment: @james large: This was my first answer. I have edited later to make the modification of his code as minimal as possible. Probably not my best idea...

Answer (score 0):

@Obicere, you are right, you dont need to lock on `postRequest` which will have performance overhead.
Use something like this inside `postRequest`

```
  public Future<Object> postRequest(final Callable<Object> request) {
        try {
            while(serviceLock.isLocked()) { // i.e acquired by setSize method
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(/*some very small time */); 
            }
            return service.submit(request);
        } finally {

        }
    }
```

Also, please consider using `ThreadPoolExecutor` instead of FixedPoolThread because in your case, it was never a fixed pool thread :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a thread pool executor explicitly and then use setMaximumPoolSize():

```
private final ThreadPoolExecutor service = new ThreadPoolExecutor(4,4,0, TimeUnit.MINUTE, new LinkedBlockingQueue());


public void setSize(final int size) {
 service.setMaximumPoolSize(size);
}
```